# Using std::map with a glm::ivec2 as KeyValue

Tags: c++, opengl

I ran into to a problem using std::map. I wanted to use it as dictionary for my terrain and wanted to access the Chunks by a glm::ivec2. I think the problem is that a glm::ivec2 does not have a less < Operator. I saw some similar posts with own structs, but i don't know if i can apply them here or how i should go about it. (sorry if some information is missing, it's my first post)

```
// init of the dictionary
std::map<glm::ivec2,Chunk> m_chunkDictionary; // init of the dictionary

//uses of the dictionary
glm::ivec2 currentChunk = glm::ivec2(round(m_scene->cam->Position.x / m_patchSize),
                                   round(m_scene->cam->Position.z / m_patchSize));
for (int x = -m_patchSize; x <= m_patchSize; x++)
{
    for (int z = -m_patchSize; z <= m_patchSize; z++)
    {
        glm::ivec2 viewedChunk = glm::ivec2(currentChunk.x + x, currentChunk.y + z );
        if(!contains(viewedChunk)) // contains is available in c++20, so i needed to write one myself
        {
            m_chunkDictionary[viewedChunk] = Chunk(m_patchSize, viewedChunk.x, viewedChunk.y, m_seed);
        }
        m_chunkDictionary[viewedChunk].render();
    }
}
```

EDIT: i tried to implement a comparator but it didn't work

```
struct cmpVecs{
    bool operator()(const glm::ivec2& a, const glm::ivec2& b) const {
        return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
    }
};

std::map<glm::ivec2,Chunk,cmpVecs> m_chunkDictionary ;
```

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xstddef(127): error C2676: Bin„rer Operator "<": "const _Ty" definiert diesen Operator oder eine Konvertierung in einen f�r den vordefinierten Operator geeigneten Typ nicht
            with
            [
                _Ty=glm::ivec2
            ]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xstddef(126): note: beim Kompilieren der Klasse Vorlage-Memberfunktion "bool std::less<glm::ivec2>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const"
            with
            [
                _Ty=glm::ivec2
            ]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xutility(1518): note: Siehe Verweis auf die gerade kompilierte Instanziierung "bool std::less<glm::ivec2>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const" der Funktions-Vorlage.
            with
            [
                _Ty=glm::ivec2
            ]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xmemory(1318): note: Siehe Verweis auf die gerade kompilierte Klasse Vorlage-Instanziierung "std::less<glm::ivec2>".
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\xmemory(1318): note: Weitere Informationen finden Sie in der Referenz zur Kompilierung der Variablenvorlage "const bool is_empty_v<std::less<glm::vec<2,int,0> > >".
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\map(75): note: Siehe Verweis auf die gerade kompilierte Klasse Vorlage-Instanziierung "std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>".
            with
            [
                _Kty=glm::ivec2,
                _Ty=Chunk,
                _Pr=std::less<glm::ivec2>,
                _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const glm::ivec2,Chunk>>
            ]
    E:\Desktop\Projekte\EZR\EZR\Glitter\Sources\Terrain.h(53): note: Siehe Verweis auf die gerade kompilierte Klasse Vorlage-Instanziierung "std::map<glm::ivec2,Chunk,std::less<glm::ivec2>,std::allocator<std::pair<const glm::ivec2,Chunk>>>".
```

Comment: `std::map` compares the keys by default using `std::less` and that is why the class of your key needs `operator<`. Alternatively, you can also pass a "comparator" as the third template argument of `std::map`. It must be a class containing `operator()` that receives two "keys" in your map and return a bool.

Comment: You should implement your comparator so it would behave "like" the `operator<`. Your current implementation behaves like `operator==` and it will potentially mess up an effective binary tree structure of your map. Try something like `return (((std::int64_t)a.x << 30) + a.y) == (((std::int64_t)b.x << 30) + b.y);` so that your keys are ordered but beware of overflow, if `x` or `y` are really large

Comment: Just made a typo, it should be `<` in my comment, not `==`

Comment: Thanks it works like Alex suggested 
`return (((std::int64_t)a.x << 30) + a.y) < (((std::int64_t)b.x << 30) + b.y);`